# How do I test method inside my class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this method:

```
fizzBuzz = () => {
    let tokens = [];
    for (let i=1; i <= this.state.upperLimit; i++) {
        if (i % 15 === 0) {
            tokens.push("fizzbuzz");
        }  else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            tokens.push("fizz");
        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            tokens.push("buzz");
        } else {
            tokens.push(i) ;
        }    
    } 
    this.setState({message: tokens.join(" ")});
}
```

which is just FizzBuzz calculation by having the user enter a upper limit to the fizzbuzz implementation inside an input field and submit it. Then the method above does some calculation and displays the message on the screen.

Snippet of what's inside of render-return:

```
<input value={this.upperLimit} type="number" min="1" placeholder="Enter Integer"/>
<button type="button" onClick={this.fizzBuzz}>Submit</button>
<label>{this.state.message}</label>
```

I'm using Jest and React-Testing-Library but I'm not sure how to test this feature. Do I need to rearrange how this is done inside of my class component to make accessible for testable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RTL suggests to test like a real user would](https://testing-library.com/docs/intro), so you should write tests based on what components display :

- change input value
- click button
- test that the requested message is present in the label
- write other similar tests with different inputs to cover all cases.

So the good news is you don't need to change anything to your component, your unit tests should be decoupled from internal implementation. [The implementation may change, without having to rewrite all your tests](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change).

See [this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/58) for some elaboration on this topic.

Your test could be something like:

```
describe('fizzbuzz', () => {
  let rtl: RenderResult;

  beforeEach(() => {
    rtl = render(<Fizzbuzz />);
  });

  test('prints correct tokens for 16', () => {
    // I assume that the input has a label which is "label for input"
    // I order to test like a real user you should grab DOM elements with visual properties/texts
    // and avoid things like CSS selectors. data-testid attribute should be the last option to use
    fireEvent.change(rtl.getByLabelText('label for input'), { target: { value: '16' } });

    // ...but you can still use querySelector/querySelectorAll
    fireEvent.click(rtl.container.querySelector('button'));

    // check that what should be returned by the function is present in the document
    expect(rtl.getByText('0 1 2 fizz 4 buzz fizz 7 8 fizz 10 11 fizz 13 14 fizzbuzz 16')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('prints correct tokens for various other cases', () => {
    fireEvent.change(rtl.getByLabelText('label for input'), { target: { value: '4' } });
    fireEvent.click(rtl.container.querySelector('button'));
    expect(rtl.getByText('0 1 2 fizz 4')).toBeTruthy();

    fireEvent.change(rtl.getByLabelText('label for input'), { target: { value: '7' } });
    fireEvent.click(rtl.container.querySelector('button'));
    expect(rtl.getByText('0 1 2 fizz 4 buzz fizz 7')).toBeTruthy();

    fireEvent.change(rtl.getByLabelText('label for input'), { target: { value: '0' } });
    fireEvent.click(rtl.container.querySelector('button'));
    expect(rtl.getByText('0')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('behaves correctly with negative input', () => {
    fireEvent.change(rtl.getByLabelText('label for input'), { target: { value: '-7' } });
    fireEvent.click(rtl.container.querySelector('button'));
    expect(rtl.container.querySelector('label').textContent).toEqual('');
  });

  // add more if you feel that some cases are not covered
  // BTW the above tests should give you a 100% test coverage
  // This should not be a goal (you can get 100% test coverage passing for wrong code),
  // but it is still a good indicator.
  // https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--coverageboolean
});
```

Comment: That's true but the issue I'm facing is accessing the method from my class component in my test. It doesn't know about it.

Comment: Why do you want to access this method in your test ? In fact RTL is opinionated about this, you can't reach component methods (see https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/58 for example). You should only test that correct things are rendered under specific circumstances and user events: test like a real user. If this method is involved, then it will be indirectly tested with this approach. RTL implies this mindset, which differs from unit testing a class in an OOP context for example.

Comment: Fine, can you give me an example of how to test the above using RTL?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a few additional questions. Just want to be sure. By the label above, is that the label that returns the results of the function? Like in the original post, I have a label that displays the message.If I named that label message, is that "label for input" in your example? In this case, it would be message? Also, why not use data-testid? Thanks!

Comment: In my example, the input element would have a label element with the text"label for input", so the RTL query findByLabelText("label for input") will return a reference to the input element. data-testid shoud be your last option, when you cannot use a visual element: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytestid, https://kentcdodds.com/blog/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change. Its always about testing like a real user.

Comment: Hi Florian, sorry, one more question. I just want to confirm this: "the input element would have a label element". Do you mean something like <label text="label for input"> <input/> </label> or something else?

Comment: Not exactly: an HTML label element associated with the input element (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Label), and which text content would be "label for input": <label for="input-id">label for input</label><input id="input-id" />. RTL provides getByLabelText(labelText) which returns the input associated to the label which text content is labelText (https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bylabeltext).